# Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

i hope you are well

I work with flutter and I want to connect to Firebase, but after installing the dependencies, during execution I get this time, I try to follow several documentation, but I still don't have the solution, Someone can- he help me

**Those are depencies : in pubspec.yaml**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
```

**my Android/App/build.gradle file**

```
plugins {
    ......
    
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

**my Android/App/build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')
}
```

**my Android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        .....
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false 
    }
```

main  file :

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Here is the error**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A145F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\dev\dev_mob\mes projets\ekingsale\ekingsale\android\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1enter image description here

Exited (1).
```

I launch and I want the application to start to continue my project

Answer (score 0):

You've applied the Google Services Gradle Plugin in the wrong block of your `app/build.gradle` script:

```
dependencies {
    .....
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false 
}
```

This is the [**dependencies**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html) block - it's not meant for declaring Gradle plugins, but rather for... dependencies - typically libraries or other modules in your Gradle project - that your app's source code would be using (for e.g. UI libraries, common utilities, reusable code from other modules, common resources, etc):

```
dependencies {
  // Example: Requiring another project
  implementation(project(":lib:common"))

  // For e.g.: referencing Jetpack Compose from an external Maven repository
  // like Google's Maven repo (https://maven.google.com/), or Maven Central
  implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4")
  implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")

  // There are different forms of what are known as "configurations" - for example, "implementation", "api", "compileOnly"
  // Plugins can also add additional ones - for example, the Android Gradle
  // Plugin adds a configuration per build variant/flavour your project
  // has defined - the defaults are "release" and "debug", resulting in
  // "releaseImplementation", "releaseApi", "debugImplementation", "debugApi"
  // configurations.
  debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.4")
}
```

The `plugins {}` block would be where you would declare it:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}
```

(This is the equivalent KotlinScript (`.kts`) syntax:)

```
plugins {
  id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
}
```

For more info, consult the [Gradle docs on plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:using_plugins).

Comment: in  Android/gradle.budle,  we dont have  plugins {}, fot to Add  id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false

Comment: If you don't have it, you can always add it yourself